# Problem with Document.execCommand("copy")

Tags: reactjs, execcommand

I am having a problem when copying values. I use Clipboard API but know Clipboard API only works with secure context (HTTPS), in my Beta it's only HTTP so Clipboard API doesn't work. So is there a way to use document.execCommand("copy") in this case?
I can simulate my code that is having problems as follows:

```
let path = 'https://google.com' 
if(navigator.clipboard) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(path).then(function() {
    console.log("Success!")
  }, function() {
    console.log("Failed!")
  });
} else {
  // Using document.execCommand("copy")
  path.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

And the problem I have is:
`Uncaught TypeError: path.select is not a function`

Can someone help me with the use case of document.execCommand("copy")? Thanks very much

Comment: please tag this with the programming language you are using

Comment: please describe the problem you are having? What is wrong with your code currently

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated the above

Comment: The error doesn't seem to have anything to do with `document.execCommand("copy");`, rather with `path.select();`. Strings do not have a `select()` function in JS. What are you trying to accomplish with that line?

Comment: I'm trying to copy that path because in my beta it's HTTP so the Clipboard API doesn't work with this context.